# How to get client certificate in WAS Liberty with SSL

Tags: ssl, websphere-liberty, client-certificates

I have configured my Was Liberty server with SSL

```
<ssl id="SSLConfig"
   keyStoreRef="KeyStore"        
   clientAuthentication="true"
   sslProtocol="TLS"
   clientKeyAlias="****"
   serverKeyAlias="***"

    />
```

It ask for the client's certificate and the Handshake ends correctly.
But after that I need to access to the client's certificate. I think the right way to do this is to use:

```
request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate");
```

But this returns null. I have tried to access this in a Filter, but it still return null.

Any Ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Do you access the HTTPS listening port directl, or via an HTTP proxy? What kind?

Comment: Hello. Directl. Is that a problem?

Comment: No, that should be the simplest/most reliable case